# Cassandra and binary files

Tags: java, upload, binary, cassandra, kundera

I'm working in a software files manager in Java with Cassandra DB. 
My database is working, and I did successfull queries using Kundera.

But now, I search for upload binary files (blob, or just files ?) in Cassandra. I tried this methods :

- Create an var in my entity in type : File, but its not working.
- Convert File into Byte[] and put an Byte[] in my entity but still not working, my Byte[] return is null !!

Do you have an idea for up small files in Cassandra database?

I hope my english is understandable... 
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/bulk-loading.

Not sure, but converting a file into byte[] may not work as you might need to open an byte stream to process it successfully.

Comment: But, I read on inet, that Cassandra not able to work with Stream because its running by thrift. 
Thanks for your link, i'll check this ;)

Comment: Were you able to successfully run file example?

Answer (score 0):

byte[] as datatype is supported in Kundera post release 2.0.7. You can convert your file to byte[] and set to entity attribute just like premitives and wrappers.
An example test case is here:
https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/blob/trunk/kundera-tests/src/test/java/com/impetus/kundera/tests/file/dao/ProfilePictureDaoTest.java